# Replacing a button on a header upon login. (Wordpress & Woocommerce & PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I am creating a website, using wordpress, for my computing course to teach people what is going to be on an examination and I am trying to configure a button on the header to show Register to unlogged in users and account for logged in users.

Using the plugins, Login/Signup Popup plugin and woocommerce, and using the built-in PHP functions which is stated below this paragraph, I have managed to get the button to change upon a user logging in and out, however, the button does not work as intended. With my PHP skills being not that great and with attempt of understanding it here is a few things I've tried and their results:

1. I've tried to use built-in function do_shortcode inside a html <a> element however this proven to work for changing the buttons but the problem is that it took me to a unrecognised url.

The code:

```
<div class="btn-cta">                                      
<a href="<?php echo do_shortcode('[xoo_el_action type="register" change_to="logout"]'); ?></a>
</div>
```

The result:

website.co.uk/my-account/<a%20href="">

2. I've configured the code in different ways removing  from inside the href quotations to the outside but that did not work.

The result:

failure

3. Lots of reconfiguring of the code which just led to failure...

Is there something that I am doing wrong or is there something that I can do to make it work differently this would be good especially because I do not want to depend on the login/signup pop up plugin for registration.

This is my current code:

```
<div class="btn-cta">                                      
<a href="<?php echo do_shortcode('[xoo_el_action type="register" change_to="logout"]'); ?></a>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a result. What is the *actual HTML* that's being generated?

Comment: When clicking on the button that is the link it takes you to

Comment: Also just realised I do not need to use change_to="" for the inside the href link. I should mention the shortcode xoo_el_action comes from the login/signup plugin too.

Comment: When clicking on signup it takes you to website.co.uk/my-account/<a20%class=>

Comment: you still haven't answered the question I asked though

Comment: I am unsure on what it is this is why I am on here

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved**

So I scoured vigorously throughout the plugin source code and such then finding zero reference to the end-point which I was being redirected to upon clicking the button. Using the process of elimination I figured it was my code that was the problem and so I reconfigured the code mentioned in the first post and when removing the <a> element surrounding the php it worked!

**Reconfiguration:**

```
<div class="btn-cta">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[xoo_el_action type="register" change_to="myaccount"]'); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[xoo_el_action type="login" change_to="logout"]'); ?>
</div>
```

That's a lesson learnt! :D